# Gaussian kernel to blur the aerial image resolution

Tags: gaussian-process, kernel-smoothing

I am using a aerial dataset - (COWC), which is a large, high quality set of annotated cars from overhead imagery.

The imagery has a resolution of 15 cm ground sample distance (GSD) that is approximately twice as good as the current best resolution of commercial satellite imagery (30 cm GSD for DigitalGlobe).

Now I need to downsample the 15cm resolution to 30cm, 45cm, 60cm resolution, so it is needed to convolve the raw imagery with a Gaussian kernel and reduce the image dimensions by half

what kernel I should apply, how would I calculate it ?

Answer (score 0):

In `R`, you could use the function [aggregate](https://search.r-project.org/CRAN/refmans/raster/html/aggregate.html) with a custom function for the `fun` argument. For example:

```
library(raster)
# create a demo raster
r <- raster()
r <- setValues(r, seq(length(r)))

# define a 5*5 Gauss filter template
gf <- focalWeight(r, 2, "Gauss")[5:9,5:9]
w <- as.vector(gf/sum(gf))

# aggregate the r 
filter <- function(x, ...) return(sum(x*w, ...))
r2 <- aggregate(r, fact=5, fun=filter)
```

If you want to aggregate your raster to a resolution where the scaling factor is **not** an integer, then you need to,  firstly, blur the image and then use `nearest neighbor` resampling to aggregate your blurred image to the desired spatial scale.